# Write a Makefile to compile .tex to .pdf

Tags: makefile, latex

The simple process on shell script might be like this:

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 
  3 latex --verbose manual.tex
  4 dvips manual.dvi
  5 ps2pdf manual.ps
  6 rm manual.{aux,log,ps,dvi}
```

There are 3 step to convert from .tex to pdf:

```
.tex -> .dvi -> .ps -> .pdf
```

To use a `Makefile` what have i tried?

```
  1 FILENAME = manual
  2 $(FILENAME).pdf: $(FILENAME).ps
  3     ps2pdf $(FILENAME).ps
  4
  5 $(FILENAME).ps: $(FILENAME).dvi
  6     dvips $(FILENAME).dvi
  7
  8 $(FILENAME).dvi: $(FILENAME).tex
  9     latex --verbose $(FILENAME).tex
```

This `Makefile` can not be success when i run `make` at first time i will get these file

```
manual.aux ,manual.dvi, manual.log
```

and error message is

```
...
l.36    \includegraphics[width=4in]{a.eps} // this error from latex
...
make: *** [manual.dvi] Error 1 // this error from Makefile
...
```

and if i run it again finally i will get `.ps` and `.pdf`.

Note that only one case this `Makefile` can work well is i have to fix `latex`'s error first then run `make`. on this way i will can get `.pdf` without any error.

And further request for a `Makefile` i also want to clean up all the files the rest are only `.tex` and `.pdf` but it's not yet implemented.

Please help me to improve my code.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run make in a clean directory?

Comment: Please include the whole error output.

Comment: @EtanReisner Please read above i already at some information from your request.

Comment: Yes, you included the single file line of the error. `make: *** [manual.dvi] Error 1`. The problem is that line is *meaningless*. Please include the rest of the output.

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry, i think now i know the cause. It because there is one error on latex about image file broken link. when i comment that error latex line and `make` agian it can be success i can get `pdf`.

Comment: make can't help you if your input is broken.

Comment: A slight issue: depending on the contents of your files, you may need to run the `latex` command two or three times.  (And possibly a `bibtex` command as well.)  In a shell script, this is easy to achieve; in a Makefile it is not so easy to ensure that the right commands are always executed in the right order and never when they aren't needed.  I have a Makefile that resolves this by renaming the results of the `latex` command depending on which stage of processing they represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you have a benign error from `latex`.  To handle such a situation, GNU Make uses the `-` prefix in front of the recipe line:

```
    -latex --verbose $(FILENAME).tex
```

and now the original error will be ignored as you like, and the whole thing should work.